# How to avoid installing HAXM every time when running avd[android studio2]

Tags: android-studio

I have installed recently the new Android Studio2. Google claims its default emulator(not genymotion) runs much faster than before.

I created new virtual device and every time i launch it, it tells me to install HAXM